# Laravel 5.4 using hasManyThrough properly

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am working on application where I want to get data from 3 different tables. `admissions_categories`, `admissions` and `programs`

`admissions` table is pivot for both `admissions_categories` and  `programs`.

I want to get all records from `admissions_categories`, including `programs` names associated with it through pivot table `admissions`. Using `hasMany` I can get multiple relation of `admissions_categories` with `admissions`, but how to get programs names from `programs` table.

I tried `hasManyThrough` example from document, but its bit different from my case, and I am not able to use the keys properly.

Here are my tables to structures.

`admissions_categories`
[image: Admission Categories Table]

`admissions`
[image: Admissions Table]

`programs`
[image: Programs Table]

Result I want is

```
admissions_categories.name, admissions_categories.last_date, programs.name (can be multiple)
```

Comment: That is not `HasManyThrough` relationship, that is `Many-To-Many` relationship

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a model for `admissions_categories` named `AdmissionCategory` you do:

```
AdmissionCategory::with('programs')->get();
```

That will eager load the relations and include the programs that are related to the `AdmissionCategory`.